# Have I graduated from a master's course?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the correct phrasing to tell the people that I have successfully obtained a master's degree? I want to convey the idea that I have had all classes and defended my dissertation.

BTW, is "defending the dissertation" a meaningful and correct phrase?

Comment: I might be generalising, but I would think you graduate from _an institution_ (e.g. _I graduated from Cambridge with a Master's_) but you complete or finish or obtain your degree.

Comment: Maybe print up some calling cards to hand out, like: *John Q. Jones, M.A., Oxon.*

Comment: "Had all classes and defended a dissertation" of course actually does _not_ mean you have a Masters degree. You need one more thing: A diploma is what confers the degree.

Comment: If someone uses "master's course" it's somewhat ambiguous whether they mean a series of classes resulting in a master's degree, or a [master class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_class), a class taught by a master (famous, not always degree-holding) in a subject.

Comment: When you say "the correct phrasing", what are you looking for precisely? The phrasing which would be most commonly used across all native English speakers? The phrasing which would be most commonly used among other holders of a postgraduate degree? The phrasing which would be preferred by a highly pedantic academic? Also, are you interested in a particular dialect / regional subset of English, or are you looking for an answer which covers global variation in usage?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm looking for, precisely, the phrasing which would be most commonly used across US native speakers of english. I'm talking with a lot of HR people and I want to convey this idea without sounding pedantic or something like that.

Comment: @MarkBeadles at least in my college, when you defend your dissertation, and are aproaved by teachers, you've earned your diploma. That's why I used it as if having the same meaning.

Answer (score 8):

Having met several people who have finished their Masters, there is one phrase they use all the time:

> I have finished my Masters...

EDIT: In view of the OP's comment below, there's also the variation:

> I finished my Masters...(number of years ago, etc.)

Comment: The only thing about using "finished" is would you say that 30 years later? It seems like there would be a point in time when this sounds odd.

Comment: @JLG  Maaaaybe "completed" in that case?  Somehow that word feels more long-term in this context.

Answer (score 6):

The normal phasings are "finished my master's [degree]", "obtained my/a master's [degree]", or "have my/a master's [degree]". The word *degree* is optional in all phrasings and should be used where it sounds better. It is frequently omitted when naming the subject (i.e. I hear "master's in engineering" more often than "master's degree in engineering"), but including it still sounds completely normal.

As for "defending the dissertation", that is both meaningful and correct, but it is not terribly common to use the word *the* in that phrase rather than a pronoun. You more often see "defending his/her/my/your disertation", even when context has already established which dissertation is being discussed.

Comment: The only other things I can think of that follow the pattern of dissertation are one's body parts. Not *I hurt **the** hand*, but *I hurt **my** hand*. Is it only body parts and dissertations? It would be a strange coincidence if it were true.

Answer (score 5):

We often have authors (with PhDs and DVMs) write that they have *earned* their degrees.

Also, as the questioner wrote, I think it is most standard to use the apostrophe with the word *master’s*. See *The New York Times* article "The Master’s as the New Bachelor’s" http://www.nytimes.com/2011/07/24/education/edlife/edl-24masters-t.html?pagewanted=all

So your sentence could be: *I earned my master's degree from State College*.

Comment: Side note: "Earned a degree" is sometimes used to specifically contract with receiving an honorary degree. When a politician or some such dignitary gives a speech at a college, they are often given an honorary degree of some sort. I have no idea what the point of this is, like who cares, but that's another story. Thus job applications and the like sometimes ask about "earned degrees" to distinguish them from honorary degrees.

Comment: Interesting. Can you find an example of that wording and post it? It seems an honorary degree is the opposite of an earned degree. I know honorees are often said to "hold an honorary doctorate" or that the degree is "awarded" or "conferred" rather than earned.

Comment: I think the intended word was *contrast*, not *contract*.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, congratulations on your accomplishment.  As a fellow M.A., whenever anyone asks, I always phrase it as "I have a Master's Degree."  This conveys everything you are looking for, I believe, and does so quite simply.

If you need a contrast, when I was in grad school, my phrasing was "I am working on a Master's Degree."

Comment: thank you very much! simple and effective formulations :)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to simply say:

> I hold a Master's (degree) (in ...).

Answer (score 1):

When I hear and read this in the United States, it most often resembles this form:

> I graduated with a Master's in Computer Science from Stanford.